# Stop arduino loop when a condition is active

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, arduino, break

I need my code to stop in the loop, i have tried to put in a break but the method sendToGCM() continues. I only want the method to be executed once, the stop while the condition

```
void loop()
{

  // Other code here giving temp a value

  if (temp > 22)
  {
    status = false;
    value["status"] = status;
    while (temp > 22)
    {
      sendToGCM(); // Sends push notification 
      break;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    status = true;
    value["status"] = status;
  }
}
```

Comment: `the method sendToGCM() continues.` What does this mean? Can we see this function?

Comment: Also if you only want the function to be called once, just dont have the while loop?

Comment: The question is not clear. `break` exits the `while` loop; the `loop` function is still called periodically as long as the board is powered.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understood you correctly, if the temperature goes 22 degrees you want to send a message, but only the first time. If you break the loop, you still enter it if you the `loop()` function is executed again.

In order to achieve what you want to do, you code will need to look something like this

```
boolean message_sent;

void loop() {
    ...
    if(temperature > 22 && !message_sent) {
        sendToGCM();
        message_sent = true;            
    }
}
```

If you want to send a message every time the temperature rises over 22 degrees you would need something like this

```
boolean message_sent;
boolean was_under_22;

void setup() {
    ...
    was_under_22 = function_that_checks_if_temp_is_under_22();
    ...
}

void loop() {
    ...
    if(temperature > 22 && was_under_22) {
        if(!message_sent) {
            sendToGCM();
            message_sent = true;
            was_under_22 = false;            
        }
    } else {
        was_under_22 = true;
        message_sent = false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** slightly adapted the code in response to Patrick Trentin's comment. The code assumes you only want to capture if the temperature rises above 22 degrees and that if the Arduino starts with over 22 degrees then no message is sent.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @wastl in your second example you state that you want to capture the *event* of *temperature rising*, however`was_under_22` is set to `true` regardless of the temperature value and that leads to a message being *fired* even when the temperature is already above `22` when *Arduino* is started. That might or might not be intended in a given application, but it does not match with your description. In fact `was_under_22` is always true in your sketch, except maybe the first iteration of the loop, so it is kind of pointless in addition to being misleading.

Comment: @wastl I think it would have been simpler to break down `if(temperature > 22 && was_under_22)`, anyway it seems to be consistent now

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting temp, then entering the loop that checks that value. A simple solution would be to update the temp value inside the while loop, to give the application a chance to break out of the while loop.

Example:

```
void loop()
{

  // Other code here giving temp a value

  if (temp > 22)
  {
    status = false;
    value["status"] = status;
    while (temp > 22)
    {
      sendToGCM(); // Sends push notification 

      //Additional code to set the value of temp, allowing the value to
      //be greater than 22.
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    status = true;
    value["status"] = status;
  }
}
```

Please note that the above example is intended to continuously send the push notification while the temp value is over 22. If that's not the intention, just remove the sendToGCM() from the while loop. You will still only send it if the temp is greater than 22, since you have the if check.